# jquery ui datepicker is not showing Month and Year in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

(https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ - version 1.11.4)

It is still working fine and let user pick up the date but only problem is that the "Month" and "Year" are not showing up until you hover the mouse on it:

[image]

What can possibly cause problem here? I checked the browser's developer tool and there is not error or warning

Comment: Your CSS may be overriding the styling of the element. Inspect one the months with [Firebug](http://bigemployee.com/4-simple-techniques-to-quickly-debug-and-fix-your-css-code-in-almost-any-browser/) by right clicking, view the CSS in the property and check if anything is assigning the colour white to the text. Is it possible to provide a live example?

Comment: I too faced the same problem.. ill check with inspect element in fire bug.. CSS color is transparent.. i changed it to black.. Now the month and Year showing me finely.. Thank you @clarus

Comment: @SabareeshwariKannan Thanks for confirming that the proposed solution resolves the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to give the following selector black color instead of white cause this means that the month & year has a white color

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select {
    color: #000;
}
```